# Convert array ['a','b'] to string ('a','b') in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to convert ['a','b'] as ('a','b') in single line

I tried below one

with item as ( select ['a','b'] as list )

select array_to_string(list,''',''') from item

Am getting

Output : a,b

Expected : a','b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below

```
with item as ( 
  select ['a','b'] as list 
)
select "('" || array_to_string(list, "','") || "')"
from item
```

with output

[image]